# Selecting in States.StringToJson function

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

It there is a way to process the result of States.StringToJson intesic function directly ?

Currently in a step function, I try to handle the error from another synchronous step function call :

```
 "OtherStepFunction": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
        "Parameters": {
          "StateMachineArn": "otherstepFunctionCall",
          "Input.$": "$"
        },
        "End": true,
        "Catch": [
          {
            "ErrorEquals": [
              "States.ALL"
            ],
            "Comment": "OtherStepFunctionFailed",
            "Next": "StatusStepFunctionFailed",
            "ResultPath": "$.error"
          }
        ]
      },
```

All errors goes in a pass flow named StatusStepFunctionFailed, with the errors output in $.error path.

The $.error is composed of the error type and the cause as an escapedJson string.

```
"error": {
   "Error": "States.TaskFailed",
   "Cause": "{\"ExecutionArn\":\"otherfunctionarm:executionid\",\"Input\":\"foooooo\"}"
 }
```

Is there any way to extract only the ExecutionARN from this input ? In my pass step, I convert the Cause path as a json, but i didn't find a way to select directly the ExectionARN part. The following :

```
"reason.$": "States.JsonMerge($.error.Cause).ExecutionArn"
```

return  `The value for the field 'reason.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call (at /States/HandleResource/Iterator/States/StatusStepFunctionFailedHandleJSON/Parameters)`

My current workaround is to use 2 pass flow, first convert the output and then formating.

Comment: May be try with StringToJson function like :

    {
        "executionId.$": "States.StringToJson($.error.Cause).ExecutionArn"}

Comment: Can you post your workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

What I did was create a task to put the Cause into a new path parameter using StringToJSON.  I put that task as the next from the error and then called the subsequent task from that one.

Using your variable names and values:

In the Catch, change the Next from StatusStepFunctionFailed to parseErrorCause

Then parseErrorCause is like this:

```
"parseErrorCause": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "Result.$": "States.StringToJson($.error.Cause)"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.parsedJSON",
      "Next": "StatusStepFunctionFailed"
    },
```

And StatusStepFunctionFailed accesses

```
"Variable": "$.parsedJSON.Result.Input",
```

to get foooooo